# Keep text inside axes during animation in Julia / matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I defined the following animation in Julia using matplotlib. The animation moves the visible area along the blue line from left to right. I placed several text elements along the blue line. I would like to make them visible as soon as they appear in the field of view (as specified by the axes limits). However, as you can see the text elements are visible on the white area outside the axes before they move into the actual axes. How can I prevent this?

```
using PyPlot, PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.animation as animation


# define initial plot
fig = figure(facecolor="white")
ax = gca()
ax[:set_ylim](-1,+1)


plot([-10,10],[0,0],"b-*",linewidth=2.0)
for i = -10:2:10
  text(i,0.3,"$(i)",fontsize=30)
end


xdata = -10:0.1:10
# use animate function to change xlim 
function animate(k)
  k+=1
  # change axis limits
  lim = ax[:set_xlim](xdata[k]-1,xdata[k]+1)
  return (lim,nothing)
end
numMaxFrames = length(xdata)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=numMaxFrames, interval=50,repeat=true)
```

**Example**: 10 is outside the axes
[image]

Comment: The `10` is there, because you program it to be there: `text(10,0.3,"10")` places the text at position (10, 0.3). From your question it does not become clear what you would like to have instead. So please edit it accordingly, clearly stating the expected behaviour.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the question. I hope this is more understandable.

Comment: So in the above plot, you would like to have the `10` not visible at all, or have it at a different position?

Comment: I would like to have the 10 appear as soon as the x-limit includes 10. The animation changes the x-limit so that the "camera" moves along the blue line from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the option *clip_on* when defining the text elements:

```
text(i,0.3,"$(i)",fontsize=30,clip_on=true)
```